# How to switch percentage width to px width after a certain point?

Tags: html, css

maybe my title did not make much sense. So first off I want to apologize for that and I'll do my best to explain what I mean.

I am trying to create a website layout with percentages. When the browser gets bigger everything looks quite nice. When making the browser smaller that's when things get really messy e.g. the menu bar gets pushed out of it's position and gets over the content area.

So what I would like is that after a certain point(before things get pushed out of there position) the width gets threaded like it was pixels and the browser has to be scrolled to see the content.

Hope you have an idea of what I meant and I would like to thank you guys in advance for any help!

Comment: CSS media queries give you this capability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries):

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  /* your code for small devices */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#menu-bar {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px; /* Your desired width */
}
```

But I suggest you to use it for the whole content page or wrapper div.

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px; /* Your desired width */
}
```

And then put other contents inside it using percentage width.